# What is the real momentum equation?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, momentum, plasma-physics

I was reading some paper on plasma physics, and when they use the momentum conservation equation (at equilibrium, i.e. $\partial_t=0$), they write:

$(1)\qquad m_i \vec{\nabla}\cdot(n_i\vec{u}_i \vec{u}_i)=-\vec{\nabla}p_i+en_i\vec{u}_i\vec{E}+en_i\vec{u}_i\wedge\vec{B}$

But during all my classes, teachers have written:

$(2)\qquad m_i n_i(\vec{u}_i\cdot\vec{\nabla}) \vec{u}_i=-\vec{\nabla}p_i+en_i\vec{u}_i\vec{E}+en_i\vec{u}_i\wedge\vec{B}$

After some algebra, one can go from (1) to (2) if the flux is conserved, i.e. $\text{div} (n_i\vec{u}_i)=0$. But since it is not the case everytime, there is a huge difference between (1) and (2). Can someone explain me the real difference and/or propose me some litterature to understand the basis ?

Comment: Both are valable if one of this conditions applies: -stationary case, - densities doesn't change in time, -flux is conserved

Comment: Yes, that's what I wrote. But if flux isn't conserved, which one is the most general ?

Comment: The former is more general, but in the substantial majority of applications, they are equivalent.  If you're dealing with chemical/nuclear reactions or an active source or sink of particles then flux isn't conserved, but I've never personally encountered such a situation.

Comment: In the case of the article I am reading, I have $\text{div}(n\vec{u}_i)=S$ with $S$ a so called "source term". So in the case of a non conservative flux, Euler should be written like (1) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both equations you wrote lack time derivative of the velocity, so both are useful under stationary condition. If first term in your continuity equation [${\partial n_i}/{\partial t} +\nabla\cdot(n_i\vec{u}_i)=0$] is null (due to stationarity), you can conclude $\nabla\cdot(n_i\vec{u}_i)=0$. The only case where this doesn't happen is a system with densities changing in time but with a constraint that fixes velocities constant. I never encountered a system like that, in that case, you would have to use the first equation only.

Edit to rephrase: You cannot have stationarity without conservation of flux. But you can have a non-stationary system with constant velocities and non conserved flux,  where the second equation does not apply.

Comment: Indeed, the model considere a stationnary flow, but not conserved (not-null divergence of flux). So, (2) is only applicable in conservative flow and (1) is the most general equation you say ?

Comment: Both are applicable under stationary flow. If the flow is not stationary, then (1) can be used if the speeds are constant in time.